# How to programmatically create new Email address with postfix

Tags: postfix

I've installed PostFix with PostFixAdmin on a server. Everything is configured and working properly. I went through the trouble of doing this so that I could create company emails on the fly. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to create new mailboxes besides going into PostFixAdmin and using the webform. Any suggestions.

Comment: You do not mention whether it's a database and/or virtual, or local user system. Is it a 'real mailbox' or an 'alias'? At any rate, I think a script would easiest as mentioned. If nothing else, just replicate what PostfixAdmin is doing, but via your own script.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script or find one to do that for you, so you just enter the email and domain or any other options, and the rest would be done by it. Also let the script after creating the mailbox to send email message, as the box will not be created till email arrives for it.
I use bash script to do that for me.

Comment: There has to be an easier way.

Comment: @Proximo it's the easiest way

Comment: So, in other words, I need to hack my own server? -.-